# Como rellenar un arrayList con imagenes

Tags: java, imagen, eclipse, arraylist

Estoy realizando el juego de Hundir la flota para ello he creado una clase main y otra clase Jugador y CPU para poner sus respectivas funciones.

Estoy intentado añadir una imágenes de unos barcos usando ArrayList con el StdDraw.

Pero no se como poner la ruta de las imágenes para que las muestre. En total debe mostrar 10 barcos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List barcos = new ArrayList();
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
        barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, null));
    }
```

Comment: El nombre del archivo es el 3er parámetro. La clase `Barco` es un suplicio.

Answer (score 0):

Donde tienes el null pones en formato String la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen.
Por ejemplo imagínate que dentro del proyecto tienes una carpeta llamada Images y dentro de ella están todas las imágenes pues sería así de sencillo:

```
barcos.add(StdDraw.picture(50, 10, "Images/barco1.jpg"));
```